# What is the concept of the RgVedic 'Brahman' in true essence?

Tags: rig-veda, brahman

The RgVea has many gods: Indra, Agni, Vayu, Vishnu, etc. It also talks about a ***God the Absolute*** called ' ***Brahman*** '. What is this ' ***Brahman*** ' actually? Agni (fire)? Vayu (wind)? Or something else?